# Wordpress remove filter wpautop not working

Tags: wp-autop

i have a trouble. I tried to use too many plugins and funciont and also

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

but it is not working.

I've added a shortcode into a text widget but wordpress add always tags p.

Why??

Comment: Does the shortcode itself add a P tag?

Comment: i don't know... inside the html file there is no tags <p>
i have always tags <p> and i don't know why. I am becoming crazy today.

Comment: Sorry you are confusing me, are you telling me that when you view the HTML file, there is no P tag? If so, then problem *solved*?

Comment: when i see the html file there is the P tag but not in the original template's html file

Answer (score 1):

WP's text widget doesn't run text through `the_content` filter, it applies `wpautop()` on saved text explicitly in code:

```
<div class="textwidget"><?php echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; ?></div>
```

This is controlled by aptly named "Automatically add paragraphs" setting at the bottom of the widget.

Comment: so... what's the solution?

Comment: I've found the solution:   [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99625/shortcode-adding-p-and-br-tags)